# npWindow->window gives 0 value in NPP_SetWindow function, plugin for Safari browser on Mac

Tags: xcode, safari, osx-yosemite, nswindow, npapi

A plugin, which works fine in firefox on windows, is being now ported to safari on Mac. we are using Xcode for development. we want a window in safari browser over which a video can be displayed. I read a code regarding NSwindow being used in NPP_SetWindow function as following:

```
NPError NPP_SetWindow(NPP instance, NPWindow* npWindow)
{
// Get a Cocoa window reference of the browser window
NP_CGContext* npContext = (NP_CGContext*)npWindow->window;
WindowRef window = npContext->window;
NSWindow* browserWindow = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithWindowRef:window] autorelease];

// Get a Cocoa reference of my carbon window
// yourCarbonWindow should be replaced with the window handle of the carbon
// window that should be tied to the Safari window.
NSWindow* myWindow = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithWindowRef:yourCarbonWindow] autorelease];

// Now create a parent child relationship
[browserWindow addChildWindow:myWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
}
```

But the problem is that npWindow->window is not carrying any value. When checked with printf, it shows 0 value, means it was not initialized or NULL.

But in Firefox it was carrying some value.
Could someone please tell how to get a NSWindow in Safari or where might be the problem ? And what is this concept of Carbon window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern versions of Safari don't support the Carbon event model (which is what your code snippet is using), only the [Cocoa event model](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI:CocoaEventModel), and per the documentation the window ref is null in that event model.

Mucking around with the window directly has been an anti-pattern in NPAPI plugins (at least on Mac) for quite a while, and with 64-bit and out-of-process plugins it has become impossible; the NSWindow isn't in your plugin's process, so you can't get a pointer to it. You should be drawing into the context or layer (depending on your drawing model) established by the API, rather than trying to show your own child window.